# How to change the textsize in a segment in UISegmentController in a XIB file

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an iPad application where i want to reduce the textsize in a segment in a UISegmentController.Please help. I also want to change the selected segment color. currently the default color we get when a segment is selected is blue. I want to change it to red. Please help me if anyone is aware of these solutions. I am trying to use a Xib file to make the segments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes...You can change the color...By adding the below code to the style your preferred the default tintcolor of segment can be changed...

```
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```